# Clean reply threads of signatures in Gmail

Tags: email, chrome, gmail

Anyone know of a Chrome extension or other tool to remove signatures in email threads when you reply.

E.g.: If I click reply to an email, my editor shows:

```
On Wed, 2 Mar 2022 at 10:54, Fred wrote:
> Want to meet at 11?
>
> --
> Humongous, big annoying signature with
> pretty company logo image embedded.
>
> On Tue, 1 Mar 2022 at 19:48 George wrote:
>> What time can we meet?
>>
>> kind regards
>> George
>> All my contact details, GPS, annual income details, etc here.
```

I would love to be able to press a button to reduce it to:

```
On Wed, 2 Mar 2022 at 10:54, Fred wrote:
> Want to meet at 11?
>
> On Tue, 1 Mar 2022 at 19:48 George wrote:
>> What time can we meet?
```

Especially when these mail threads get quite long, it makes it difficult to read through the tortuous chain with all the signatures, cutesy fonts and images people stuff on the end of every single bloody email they send.